# Change code to use list comprehension

Tags: python

Very new to Python and trying to work through some examples online to teach myself. I fixed one problem but when I was talking to a friend he told me I should use list comprehension to complete such a task. The only thing is I can't see how I could implement the task using list comprehension rather than a generator function. This is the code that works, all help is appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def find_longest_word(sentence):
    word = sentence.split()
    long_word = max(len(s) for s in word) # [x for x in range]    
    print "The length of the longest word is: ",long_word
    #return
find_longest_word("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog with pneumonia") # For testing
```

Thanks

Comment: `max([len(s) for s in sentence.split()])`

Comment: There's pretty much no reason to use a list comprehension here. A genexp is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about list comprehension quick...

Let's take a normal `for loop` like this:

```
sentence = 'Hello how are you doing today?'
lengths = []
for word in sentence.split():
    lengths.append(len(word))
```

This is the equivalent of this:

```
[len(word) for word in sentence.split()]
```

The normal syntax of a single for loop list comprehension is `[value for value in list]`
Where you can see `for value in list` which is the same as a normal for loop. The only difference is instead of the value to return being after the for loop, it is before.

For your case you can do this: `max([len(word) for word in sentence.split()])`

Comment: Thanks ZWiki. Just to show my complete ignorance but why is that better than the code I wrote? I can't see why using list comprehension makes the code any better (in reality I find it harder to read) so is it not the same thing just formatted differently?

Comment: @Signpost87, take a look at this article: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops
Although `list comprehension` is more or less just syntactical over normal for loops, you can use a generator function (better for large loops as it will keep an index of where in the loop it is the next time around)

Comment: @ZWiki: In your suggestion `max([len(word) for word in sentence.split()])` there is no need to bring the list to life with the square brackets,  `max(len(word) for word in sentence.split())` works just as fine and most likely performs better.

Comment: @PedroMDuarte use `timeit.timeit` to compare the times of the two, you will be surprised

Comment: @ZWiki  honestly I am surprised:  In [5]: %time max([len(word) for word in (sentence*10000).split()])
Wall time: 91.1 ms
Out[5]: 6

In [6]: %time max(len(word) for word in (sentence*10000).split())
Wall time: 108 ms
Out[6]: 6

Comment: @ZWiki, do you know why it is the case?

Comment: @PedroMDuarte your code produces a `generator`. Although it is better for large lists, `generators` have initial setup time that out-weighs the time of `list comprehension` for smaller loops

Answer (score 2):

a list comprehension doesn't seem apt for the result you seek. Instead, you can pass the list `word` to the built-in function `max()` with a positional parameter `key`: a function which operates on every element in `word` and returns a value( length, in this case) as ordering value:

```
len(max(word,key=len))
```

Comment: Why would you pass `word` as a star-arg? That just makes things break if `word` only has one element.

Comment: @user2357112 corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Better than list comprehension, use a higher-order function (a function that can take another function as an argument) such as `max`.  The `key` argument to `max` will be applied to each element in `sentence.split()` and ordering will be determined based on that.  Here are a couple of examples:

```
>>> def find_longest_word(sentence):
...     longest = max(sentence.split(), key=len)
...     print(longest, len(longest))
...
>>> find_longest_word("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
quick 5
>>> find_longest_word("The quick brown fox juuuuumps over the lazy dog")
juuuuumps 9
>>>
```

Notice that `len` is the python built-in function to determine the length of an object.

Answer (score 0):

To use list comprehension you could replace `max(len(s) for s in word)` with `max([len(s) for s in word])`, but there is no need to do this, both examples will work fine. You just need to understand how this list comprehension works in order to solve the task. For beginner it is much easier to understand how this works:

```
def find_longest_word(sentence):
    res = []
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        res.append(len(word))
    long_word = max(res)
    print "The length of the longest word is: ", long_word

find_longest_word("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

than to use some list comprehensions or generators.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to post my version... just cant resist a list comprehension question - how pythonic!

```
>>> s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog with pneumonia"
>>> w = max([word for word in s.split()], key=len)
>>> print('{} {}'.format(w, len(w)))
pneumonia 9
```